# Building Cloud Service not generating CsPack file

Tags: azure, sdk, package, building

I have one cloud service project, one webrole and one worker role. I have included the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Targets.

When I am building through MSBuild its not generating the package, I can build a task for CsPack, but wanted to get it done via CorePublish which already does include the CsPack command. But CorePublish is not getting called during MsBuild. Please reply if someone has done it.

Comment: did you take a look here ? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-continuous-delivery/#step2 in worst case scenario add a powershell script to package after building (with the Azure cmdlets)

Comment: Did you run `msbuild \t:Package`?